# Ext JS library not installed correctly in Oozie

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I'm getting the following message when I access to the oozie UI.

> Oozie web console is disabled.
>
> To enable Oozie web console install the Ext JS library.

I'm using HDP distribution and installed through ambari service installer.

I tried to follow the following links:

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.4/bk_command-line-installation/content/install_oozie_rpms.html

Getting the following message when trying to install it using yum:

> $ sudo yum install extjs-2.2-1
>
> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
>
> Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
>
> - base: centos.mirror.ptisp.pt
> - epel: epel.besthosting.ua
> - extras: centos.mirror.ptisp.pt
> - updates: centos.alpha-labs.net
>
> No package extjs-2.2-1 available.
>
> Error: Nothing to do

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/61363/issue-oozie-web-console-is-disabledto-enable-oozie.html

I can't find the place in Amabari UI where to place the property oozie.authentication.cookie.domain.

What can I fix it? I'm really lost.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-1358 looks vaguely related. Have you tried a newer version of extjs?

Comment: i can't find any newer version from yum

Comment: I finally found a third party vendor for this version in the following link (although cloudera source): http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-Processing-and-Workflow/enable-oozie-web-console/td-p/22687. Although the war file says that it could include successfully the extjs library, i'm still getting the same error at the oozie web console UI. Maybe permissions problem?

Comment: Looks like Ambari did not install the HDP repo, but you edit `oozie-site.xml` under oozie service configurations. If the property doesn't exist, you use the custom section at the very bottom of Ambari pane

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I finally solved it by installing a third-party version of ExtJS from the following url: http://archive.cloudera.com/gplextras/misc/ext-2.2.zip

Then following the steps:

1. Stop Oozie service from Ambari
2. Copy it to the path:

> /usr/hdp/current/oozie-client/libext/

3. Regenerate the war file by executing:

> $ /usr/hdp/current/oozie-server/bin/oozie-setup.sh prepare-war

4. Start Oozie again

Hope it helps!

Step by step instruction:

```
wget http://archive.cloudera.com/gplextras/misc/ext-2.2.zip

sudo cp ext-2.2.zip /usr/hdp/current/oozie-client/libext/
sudo chown oozie:hadoop /usr/hdp/current/oozie-client/libext/ext-2.2.zip
sudo -u oozie /usr/hdp/current/oozie-server/bin/oozie-setup.sh prepare-war
```

Comment: It fully helped. Would never get to the solution by myself. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks for this answer!  Worked like a charm.

Comment: Works perfectly on Hortons Sandbox 3. Thank you!